# R Data Frame Type of Row Selection but for Java 8 ArrayList

Tags: java, r

I want to concisely select elements from an ArrayList like I can do in R.  For example, in R I can select rows where the index column contains values greater than 1500 and copy that result to a new data frame:

```
ndf = df[df$index>1500,]
```

In Java 8, I would like to do the equivalent with an ArrayList.  The most concise way I could come up with is this:

```
List<IndexCount> signficantRowIndexList = new ArrayList<>();
<the list gets loaded with some objects>

List<IndexCount> selectedList = new ArrayList<>();

signficantRowIndexList.stream()
        .filter((ic)->ic.index > 1500)
        .forEach((ic)->selectedList.add(ic));
```

Is this THE most concise way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should collect the stream into a `List`.
Using `collect()` seems more natural in your case as you want to create a new `List` from the current stream :

```
List<IndexCount> selectedList = signficantRowIndexList.stream()
        .filter(ic-> ic.index > 1500)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

As a side note, parenthesis are not required if you have only one argument as lambda parameter.